# How to set Zend Framework session to one year

Tags: session, zend-framework

I've CMF ZF1.11 + Doctrine2 + Doctrine-Extension + Symfony2 DI
When I try to set session time using next in configuration file

```
;-------------- Session --------------------;

resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/sessions"
resources.session.cookie_lifetime = 31536000
resources.session.use_only_cookies = true
resources.session.gc_maxlifetime = 31536000
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 31536000
```

It online helps a bit - session keeps near a hour or so and then lost.

Any more advice how to set session time to 1 year.

Thanks

Comment: Have you changed `session.gc_maxlifetime` in PHP settings?

Comment: @Volvox Yes, you see the setting in the configuration in the question - it affects PHP by using `ini_set()`.